# Translate few Pali sentences

Tags: pali

Cant find a translation online anywhere, just a quote.

Samanattata ' ti samanasukhadukkhabhavo. Ekacco hi danadisu ekam ' pi na paccasimsati. Ekasane nisajjam ekapallanke sayanam ekato bhojanan ' ti evam samanasukhadukkham paccasimsati. So sace gahatthassa jatiya pabbajitassa silena sadiso hoti tass ' ayam samanattata katabba.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's no complete English translation of the AN commentary. My Pali isn't very good, so I pieced this together with my handy dictionary. Rough translation:

> Equanimity means the state of being impartial towards pleasure and pain. Some, even when receiving donations/generosity, do not feel satisfaction. They sit in one place, lie down on one side (on a simple mat), and eat food from one bowl. Equanimity is achieved in this way. If a householder has similar virtue to one who has left the householder life and entered a state of being homeless, this equanimity can be achieved by them.

Comment: Interesting. I tried translating it myself, I managed to find the words in various dictionaries, and based on that and some other things and my attempt goes like this:

"Self-equality (or making oneself equal) is to be equal in pleasure and pain (with others). Some people do not desire to be given things. In one place sitting together in seats and eating foods together of equal pleasure and pain is what they desire. If one is a householder or a matted hair ascetic, embracing them as equal, this is how self-equality should be done."

Comment: I was using an already existing explanation I found which sounds similar to this to get this idea about 'making oneself equal' (and it does have atta there). The context is how to make someone (feel like) a member of the community, how to befriend people. It mentions that one of the ways is dana, to give them things, to share things with them, thats why here it mentions some people dont desire that. Thats why I think samana is better translated as equality than equanimity, and etako as together rather than as one, and ekapallanke as siting together rather siting in one place.

Comment: Ven. Sujato translates *samānattatā* in the sutta as "equality" https://suttacentral.net/an4.32/en/sujato -- Bhikkhu Bodhi translates it as "impartiality" https://suttacentral.net/an4.32/en/bodhi

Comment: @ChrisW thanks! I was using the PTS dictionary but "equality" seems to be more correct here.

Comment: @zelenisok Your translation might be better than mine! As I said my Pali is really not good, my method is basically to look through the PTS dictionary and then the Concise Pali-English Dictionary to try to cobble things together.

Comment: I was looking primarily at wisdomlib and wiktionary, lol, both are pretty good sources, wiktionary has some stuff, some not, wisdomlib has lots, and an option of searching a word as 'prefix', where I type it without last few letters, and it gives me all results starting like that, so that the suffixes don't mess up my search. Also I browsed dictionary.sutta.org for the "silena" word to find similar stuff, that was basically the only one I had problems finding on the previous two sources. That and ekapallanke, where I fortunately knew to search without the prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you know this already.

It's quoted in this document:

- [http://www.dhammarain.org.tw/canon/pali-tipitaka-f1/4-Anguttaranikaya/AA-2~4.doc](http://www.dhammarain.org.tw/canon/pali-tipitaka-f1/4-Anguttaranikaya/AA-2%7E4.doc)

Here's a screenshot of the page:

> [image]

According to that it's AN 4.32 i.e. after AN 4.31 (Cakka sutta) and before AN 4.33 (Siha sutta).

Here are those on suttacentral:

- https://suttacentral.net/an4-cakkavagga

> [image]

But the Pali text translated in AN 4.32 on Suttacentral isn't the same (and is much shorter).

You might get a reply by asking the author. There's an email address on the last page of the document, and another though similar email address on the translated home page of http://www.dhammarain.org.tw/ -- where they offer lessons in Pali (listed as "2023 Event Information").

Comment: I believe the "vaṇṇanā" suffix mean that it's a commentary (not from the sutta itself). The citation [here](http://kusala.online-dhamma.net/%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E8%B3%87%E6%96%99/%E5%8D%97%E5%82%B3%E4%BD%9B%E6%95%99%E5%9C%96%E6%9B%B8%E9%A4%A8%20Theravada%20Buddhism%20E-Library/046%20%E6%96%87%E7%AB%A0%20Articles/12%20Essays%20On%20Buddhism%202.htm) also points to the commentary.

Comment: Nice answer! By the way, you can change the image size by adding *s, m,* or *l* before the file extension, (small, medium and large, respectively).